# Can I update one iframe from another?

Tags: iframe

I want to update one iframe from another. I have a link in one iframe which should update the content of the other iframe. There is link in checkresult.html which should update the statusmessage.html.

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
    <td width="10%">
    <iframe id="test" src ="checkresult.html" height="1000px" width="100%" frameborder="1">
    </iframe >
    </td>   
    <td align="left" width="80%">
    <iframe id="msgstatus"  name = "test" src ="StatusMessage.html" align="left"  width="100%" height="1000px" frameborder="1" >

    </iframe></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like a link in one frame to open in another, you need to refer to the other's `name` attribute in the link's `target` attribute. So in this case, a link in `checkresult.html` would need to have a target of `test` to open in the `msgstatus` frame:

```
<a href="something.html" target="test">Link text</a>
```